# Exactly, What is the Completeness Axiom?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

**Completeness Axiom:** The [Completeness Axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_of_the_real_numbers) states for every non-empty subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that $A$ has a least upper bound.

There are many equivalent definitions to this. But I am looking for the exact axiom above that makes sense of the following scenario and not looking for an equivalent definition here.

**Scenario:** Consider $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}| x^2<2\}$. It is well known that this set does **NOT** have a least upper bound. This is a fact!

That being said....

- $A$ is non-empty
- $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$

$\therefore$ By the Completeness Axiom, it should have a least upper bound.

What should I be including in the Completeness Axiom differently to avoid this contradictory logic? I feel like there is something missing in this Axiom that is a little more detailed here but isn't written in most textbooks.

Comment: $A$ has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$, which is $\sqrt{2}$, whereas it does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: I think the point you are missing is that it is not required for the least upper bound to be in the set itself. So in your example, $\sqrt{2}$ is the least upper bound of $A$, despite $\sqrt{2}\notin A$.

Comment: The completeness axiom merely states that a nonempty set bounded above has a least upper bound. It doesn't say what kind of number it has to be though. Since we treat $\mathbb{R}$ as the universal set, we can assume that, at minimum, if there's a least upper bound, it is a real number. Now it might be a rational number, but it doesn't have to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Scenario:** Consider $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}| x^2<2\}$. It is well known that this set does **NOT** have a least upper bound. This is a
> fact!

Not exactly. It does not have an upper bound **in $\mathbb Q$**.

"Having an upper bound" is not a property that exists in isolation. To speak of an upper bound, you need three things:

1. A set $X$
2. A set $A\subseteq X$
3. An ordering $\leq$, defined on $X$.

For your set, if $X=\mathbb Q$, then the set $A=\{x\in \mathbb{Q}| x^2<2\}$ does not have an upper bound.

However, if $X=\mathbb R$, then the same set **does** have an upper bound, and that upper bound is $\sqrt 2$. It is relatively easy to show both properties an upper bound must have:

1. $\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound of $A$.
2. If $y<\sqrt{2}$, then $y$ is **not** an upper bound of $A$.

Comment: That's what I am missing! The fact that it should specify that it is in $\mathbb{Q}$. Makes sense now. I could even switch the wording here that it has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$. Correct? Would that be more appropriate here for the Axiom? Specifying in context to what makes more sense to me.

Comment: @WilliamGarske Yes, that would be a sensible way to word it. The set has a least upper bound in $\mathbb R$, but it does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb Q$.

Answer (score 4):

*You have missed a hypothesis in the statement of the completeness axiom: $A$ must be nonempty **and bounded above**. For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ is a nonempty set of reals without a least upper bound, which isn't a problem since $\mathbb{Z}$ doesn't have any upper bounds at all. This doesn't affect the specific example you're asking about, but it is important.*

---

Actually, the set $S=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x^2<2\}$ **does** have a least upper bound ... *in the real numbers*. It is true that:

- $S$ doesn't have a *maximum element*, and
- $S$ doesn't have a least upper bound *in the rational numbers*,

but neither of those facts contradicts the existence of a least upper bound of $S$ in $\mathbb{R}$: that is, a real number $r$ such that $r$ is $\ge$ every element of $S$ and no $s<r$ is $\ge$ every element of $S$. This $r$ is just $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Isn't it that $\{ x\in \mathbb{R} : x^2<2 \}$ has a least upper bound instead?

Comment: @WilliamGarske No. $\sqrt{2}$ is the least upper bound of $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x^2<2\}$ **and** of $\{x\in\mathbb{R}: x^2<2\}$.

Comment: @WilliamGarske It may help to turn things around: why do you think that $\sqrt{2}$ is **not** the least upper bound of $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}: x^2<2\}$? Do you think $\sqrt{2}$ isn't an upper bound? Do you think there is a strictly smaller upper bound?

Comment: I think what I am missing is the specification that it has a least upper bound of $\mathbb{R}$ here in the axiom. Is that correct? By definition of a least upper bound, it should say least upper bound of a particular set here - I believe.